# Is it possible to get a crash log due to expiration of provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, crash, ios-provisioning, crash-log

When an application doesn't start or it goes home screen right after tapping the application, do I have a way to know whether it is because of expiration of its provisioning profile or other reason?

I couldn't find them in crash logs from Finder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the app's provisioning profile has expired, you will see it in the Device console.  If you have access to the device, plug it into your Mac and fire up Xcode.

Starting with Xcode 6, to view the console output of a connected device:

Connect your device.
Build and deploy the app to the device using either the CLI or Studio.
Sync the application to the device using iTunes (if you are not building directly to device).
Launch Xcode.

Open the Devices window. From the menu, select Window > Devices.

Select your device from the left bar.

Click the Show the device console button ( [image: expand icon] ) to expand the console.
[image: device console]

Once you have the console up, click the trash can to clear it, then on the device try to launch the app.  If the provisioning profile for the app has expired, I believe you will see a message like the following:

`A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found`

Comment: The "Show device console" button should win an award for undiscoverability!

Comment: I agree.  It's one of those things that once you know it's there, it's great.  But even trying to tell other devs about it is difficult.