# Ad Hoc application distribution

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution

I want to send my application to my customer for testing. He send me his UDID. I added my and his UDID's in my member center.

Then in keychain I requested for new certificate and save it on desktop. Then in member center I've created 'App Store and Ad Hoc' (Sign your iOS app for submission to the App Store or for Ad Hoc distribution) certificate with my requested CSR file and download it.

Also, I've created an application ID in member center with bundle identifier from xCode.

Then I've created 'Ad Hoc' (Create a distribution provisioning profile to install your app on a limited number of registered devices) provisioning profile, select created distribution certificate and created earlier application ID and choose customer's and my UDID. Then I downloaded .mobileprovision file to desktop and double clicked on it to install (but when I clicked nothing happend I don't know if it have to be like this).

Then in xCode I set Code Signing Identity: debug to developer profile and release to distribution profile. Then I've cleaned and build the project.

Then I archive my project and export it for Ad Hoc Deployment and save on desktop.

But when I want to check it on my iPhone before sending .ipa and .mobileprovision to my customer it doesn't install. I drag'n'drop these two files on iTunes then select my phone, click on install an app and the synchronize my phone. On my phone the application appears with gray icon, started to install and immediately cancels.

Please, tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try Apple Developer's Link https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html or http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-test-your-app-on-an-ios-device--mobile-13861

Comment: @PavanJangid I know how to test an application from xCode. I want to test my .ipa on my iPhone so if it will work then on my customer's iPhone it will works well too. I don't want my customer to have some issues with it.

Comment: Open up the device console in Xcode and look at the error message that shows up when the failed install happens.  That will allow us to give you a solution.

Comment: Here's instructions if you don't know how to look at the device console: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30992454/3708242

Answer (score 0):

If your all steps are right. But, when you are going to make ipa then you don't need to install provisioning profile on your device. when you are making .ipa file it already uses your provisioning profile. so, don't install in your device .provisioning profile. Try this it may help you and solve your problem.

Comment: Did you mean just drag only the .ipa file to iTunes? If yes - it doesn't work, cancels as I said before(

Comment: Then in xCode I set Code Signing Identity: debug to developer profile and release to distribution profile. Then I've cleaned and build the project. -- Change this if you are using ad hoc profile then don't keep debug to developer profile keep both in distribution profile that is wrong.