# Re-sign IPA for iOS 9

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ipa, ios-provisioning

I am trying to resign my ad hoc to enterprise certificate. It is working well for ios 8 and below. I take instructions from these link.

[Re-sign IPA (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896029/re-sign-ipa-iphone)

http://www.enterpriseios.com/forum/topic/Resigning_3rd_party_apps

However, I am now doing on iOS 9 device and it show me this error when I drag and drop ipa file into device.

**"application could not be verified"**

How shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

This condition mainly occurs in phone with IOS9.Is it right?

IOS9 or XCode7 disables the unsafe HTTP requests,use https instead.
You should update your system and Xcode to version7,then package your app again use xcode7.

If it works,recall me.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can happen if there is an app on the device (possible the same app without the new signing) that has the same bundle ID as the re-signed IPA.  Make sure you've deleted any old version of the app on the device and try again.

Comment: yes i delete all my application though. It is not okay yet.

Comment: Can you post the details from the device's console.  That will give us more information that may lead to a solution.  My thought is that this is a device-specific issue, not an iOS9 specific issue.  Do you have access to any other iOS9 devices?  If so, try installing on another iOS 9 device.

Comment: I have tried on another device, iphone 6s. It is still not okay yet.

Comment: Do you know how to look at a device's console?  That will really help you / us get to the root cause.  Open Xcode, go to the Devices window (in the Window menu).  Find the device plugged into your mac on the left and select it.  It should show you the console in the bottom right pane.  Clear the console, then try again to install the app.  Post what the console says here and maybe we can help.

Comment: It doesn't show anything now. Normally, when I run from xcode, it show all the log but now no console log. Do I need to enable somewhere?

Comment: For how to bring up the console, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30992454/3708242  Make sure you are looking at the device console, not the device logs.