# Not able to install ipa into iphone

Tags: iphone, xamarin.forms, provisioning-profile, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution

When I try to install ipa into the iphone using itunes,it stuck on "Installing" and application from iphone disappears suddenly.I have read realated QAs but didn't get any help.I have tried installing ipa after changing my bundle Id ,I have cofigured provision profile correctly still not able to install.I am not getting what is the problem.Please help !

Comment: This usually is pointing out that the device isn't in the provisioning profile, so you might want to double-check that. Also you could connect the device to Xcode and see what the logs say.

Comment: You need to  look at the device console to see exactly why it is failing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30992454/3708242

Comment: My guess is that you may have updated the provisioning profile, but for some reason it is still building with the old provisioning profile.  I would delete the local provisioning profiles and re-download the new provisioning profile with the new bundle id.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have completed all of the steps setting up an `ad hoc provisioning profile` as listed [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/48750/testflight-sdk-tutorial), you should now have an `.ipa` file exported to disk. Instead of using iTunes, try using Xcode. Goto `Xcode > Window > Devices` and choose your iPhone. Scroll down to the bottom of the app list and press the `+` button. Choose your `.ipa` file and click `Open`. The app will now be installed to your iPhone. Hope this helped :)

[image: click '+' button]

Answer (score 0):

- To install your IPA into the iphone, your iPhone UDID should must have listed in the device list of your developer account.
- IPA should be made through AdHoc Developer profile Or AdHoc Distribution Profile.
- Your Phone should have the same or above as deployment target (i.e IOS Version).

Check these steps and try again, hope you will get success.

Thanks